# Syntax Error during inner join of two select statements

Tags: mysql, join

The sql query below is having some error during inner join part and this is the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT SERIAL_NO FROM STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE
>   mvtLn INNER ' at line 3

```
SELECT
  wm.CID,
  wm.DOC_ID,
  wm.DOC_TYPE,
  wml.SERIAL_NO,
  wml.WH_MVT_NO,
  wm.PROD_ID,
  wm.LOT_CODE,
  wm.WH_CODE,
  wm.BIN_CODE,
  wml.MVT_DATE,
  wm.BATCH_NO,
  wm.MVT_TYPE,
  wm.PROD_NAME,
  wm.COMMENT,
  wm.REMARK,
  wm.NOTE,
  wm.INSTRUCTION 
FROM
  STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE wml 
INNER JOIN
  STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT wm 
    ON wml.CID=wm.CID 
    AND wml.WH_MVT_NO=wm.WH_MVT_NO 
WHERE
  wml.CID = 70200009 
  AND (
    wm.MVT_TYPE != 'TFOUT' 
    AND wm.MVT_TYPE != '3TFOUT'
  )     
  AND wml.SERIAL_NO IN (
    (
      SELECT
        SERIAL_NO 
      FROM
        STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE mvtLn 
      INNER JOIN
        STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT mvt 
          ON mvtLn.CID = mvt.CID 
          AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE = mvt.PFC_CODE 
          AND mvtLn.WH_MVT_NO = mvt.WH_MVT_NO 
      where
        mvtLn.CID = 70200009 
        AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE ='SG' 
        AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE >= '2016-04-01 00:00:00.0' 
        AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE <='2016-06-30 00:00:00.0'  
        AND mvt.WH_CODE = 'IDJKT' 
        AND mvt.BIN_CODE = 'IMP'
    )AS a     
  INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        SERIAL_NO 
      FROM
        STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE mvtLn 
      INNER JOIN
        STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT mvt 
          ON mvtLn.CID = mvt.CID 
          AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE = mvt.PFC_CODE 
          AND mvtLn.WH_MVT_NO = mvt.WH_MVT_NO 
      where
        mvtLn.CID = 70200009 
        AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE ='SG' 
        AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.0' 
        AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE <='2016-03-31 00:00:00.0'  
        AND mvt.WH_CODE = 'CL' 
        AND mvt.BIN_CODE = 'PSADEPOT'
    )AS b 
      ON a.SERIAL_NO = b.SERIAL_NO
    )  
    AND wm.MVT_DATE  BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2016-06-30 00:00:00.0'  
ORDER BY
  wml.SERIAL_NO,
  wml.MVT_DATE
```

Comment: Query is totally desperate to debug :) Try to simplify it by removing parts essential for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
SELECT wm.CID, wm.DOC_ID, wm.DOC_TYPE, wml.SERIAL_NO, wml.WH_MVT_NO
    , wm.PROD_ID, wm.LOT_CODE, wm.WH_CODE, wm.BIN_CODE, wml.MVT_DATE
    , wm.BATCH_NO, wm.MVT_TYPE, wm.PROD_NAME, wm.COMMENT, wm.REMARK
    , wm.NOTE, wm.INSTRUCTION
FROM STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE wml INNER JOIN STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT wm ON wml.CID = wm.CID
AND wml.WH_MVT_NO = wm.WH_MVT_NO
WHERE wml.CID = 70200009
    AND wm.MVT_TYPE != 'TFOUT'
    AND wm.MVT_TYPE != '3TFOUT'
    AND wml.SERIAL_NO IN (
            SELECT a.SERIAL_NO FROM -- You missed this. I thought....
            (
                SELECT SERIAL_NO
                FROM STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE mvtLn
                INNER JOIN STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT mvt
                ON mvtLn.CID = mvt.CID
                AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE = mvt.PFC_CODE
                AND mvtLn.WH_MVT_NO = mvt.WH_MVT_NO
                WHERE mvtLn.CID = 70200009
                AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE = 'SG'
                AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE >= '2016-04-01 00:00:00.0'
                AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE <= '2016-06-30 00:00:00.0'
                AND mvt.WH_CODE = 'IDJKT'
                AND mvt.BIN_CODE = 'IMP'
            ) a
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT SERIAL_NO
                FROM STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT_LINE mvtLn
                INNER JOIN STOCK.WAREHOUSE_MVT mvt
                ON mvtLn.CID = mvt.CID
                AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE = mvt.PFC_CODE
                AND mvtLn.WH_MVT_NO = mvt.WH_MVT_NO
                WHERE mvtLn.CID = 70200009
                AND mvtLn.PFC_CODE = 'SG'
                AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.0'
                AND mvtLn.MVT_DATE <= '2016-03-31 00:00:00.0'
                AND mvt.WH_CODE = 'CL'
                AND mvt.BIN_CODE = 'PSADEPOT'
            ) b ON a.SERIAL_NO = b.SERIAL_NO )
    AND wm.MVT_DATE BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2016-06-30 00:00:00.0'
ORDER BY wml.SERIAL_NO, wml.MVT_DATE
```

Comment: Yeah i miss that part but i getting serial_no is ambiguous error and after i put a bracket outside two select statement and set it as c and c.SERIAL_NO later it throw me syntax error at c

Comment: I've fixed `serial_no is ambiguous error`. Check it again please.

Comment: I just afraid it will take the serial no from a only but not after inner join

Comment: Nope, `INNER JOIN` will fetch records which match in both `a` and `b` on condition `a.SERIAL_NO = b.SERIAL_NO`. You can just run this subquery and check it.